# WIN32,C/C++:How to generate the window which have a menu by using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-studio-code, win32gui

I'm learning to create WIN32 apps in C++.
I originally used Visual Studio, but recently I've been using VSCode because of its lightness of operation.
However, to the extent that I can only write in .cpp, I have no problems. But I can't compile or embed .rc well...
Is it possible to create a WIN32 app with embedded resources in VSCode?
We are using VSCode, CMake (3.18.0), the compiler is VS2019 cl. The version of SDK is 10. I don't use a resource editor, I write by hand. (I'll get an editor if I need one, but I'd like to know if there's a way to write it by hand...)
I was told that I can compile .rc by using rc.exe, but I got a "winres.h I can't read winres.h" and an error appears.
Furthermore, even if the compilation succeeds, I don't know how to link the .res from there. I'm not even sure how to set up the build and CMake options.
I would appreciate any advice you can give me.

```
//c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/cppwinrt",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/winrt",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/atlmfc/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/cppwinrt",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/winrt",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/atlmfc/include",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x64",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ]
            },
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**

```
    //CMakeLists.txt
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
    project(sample_menu VERSION 0.1.0)

    include(CTest)
    enable_testing()

    set_source_files_properties(menu.rc PROPERTIES LANGUAGE RC)
    add_executable(sample_menu WIN32 "sample_menu.cpp")

    set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
    set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
    include(CPack)
```

**

```
    //resource(sample_manu.rc)
    #include<winres.h>
    #include"resource.h"
    
    sample_menu MENU
    BEGIN
        POPUP "ファイル(&F)"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "終了(&X)",                            IDM_END
        END
        POPUP "オプション(&O)"
            MENUITEM "オプション(&1)\tShift + Ctrl + 1",    IDM_OPT1
            MENUITEM "オプション(&1)\tShift + Ctrl + 2",    IDM_OPT2
        END
        POPUP "ヘルプ(&H)"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "About(&A)\tCtrl + A",                 IDM_ABOUT
        END
    END
```

**

```
//resource.h
#include<winres.h>

#define IDM_END     101
#define IDM_OPT1    102
#define IDM_OPT2    103
#define IDM_ABOUT   104
```

**

```
//sample_menu.cpp(parts of)
#include<Windows.h>
#include"resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);

TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("winapp");

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hCurInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpsCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {                                                       
    ...
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//Registering the Window class
ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    ...
    wc.lpszMenuName = TEXT("sample_menu");          //the menu name(If there is no menu,set to NULL)
    ...
    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc));
}

//Generating the Window
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd;                              //Window handle(used to manipulate Window)

    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        ...
        NULL,                               //the menu handle(set to NULL when using the class menu)
        ...);
    ...
}

//Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    
    switch (msg){
    ...
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wp)){
            case IDM_END:
                SendMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
                break;
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                MessageBox(hWnd,TEXT("初めてのメニュー"),TEXT("About"),MB_OK);
                break;
            default:
                return (DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wp,lp));
        }
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: "Is it possible to create a WIN32 app with embedded resources in VSCode?" - Whatever you use to write your code, be it vscode, notepad, vim or Emacs is *irrelevant*. You can do whatever you want, no matter what editor you use. As for resource files, that has nothing to do with your editor/IDE.

Comment: To me this is more of a CMake problem than anything. You probably wanted to tag for that instead of one of your lesser important tags.

Comment: @JesperJuhl _As for resource files, that has nothing to do with your editor/IDE_  It does, actually.  The full version of Visual Studio has a built-in graphical resource editor.  You rarely have to edit your .RC files by hand.

Comment: @PaulSanders Sure, it does have that, but you can still build and use resource files without using Visual Studio. So I stand by my previous comment; your IDE has nothing to do with that. It is *not* a requirement.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you are working with C++, why the C language tag?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has inheritance, so that a button class can inherit from a window class.  The C language doesn't.  Also, I don't recommend for beginners to mix C and C++; as it makes the project more complex and complexity breeds defects.  Please edit your language tags appropriately.

Comment: @tho Distinct as the languages C and C++ are, they share a common build model. This is especially true for the linker. This question is ultimately about linking, and a solution applies to both C and C++, unchanged. Arbitrarily removing either tag will accomplish one thing only: Making this Q&A harder to discover.